# How to perform an R script on multiple files and put the output of each file in one single csv file?

Tags: r, bash, csv, stdin

I am doing some modelling analysis and I would like to plot the boundary length between cell-type 1 and  cell-type 2 over time.

Here's what I've done so far:

1. Generated an output per 100 Monte-Carlo Steps (MCS) of the python-based simulation that specifies what the cellular lattice looks like by giving the cellular identity (cell-id[400 cells in total] and cell-type[either 1 or 2]) for each x- and y-coordinate. I have about 1000 of these files (columns with cell_id, cell_type, x-coordinate and y-coordinate, and 10.000 rows) one per 100 MCS, all files located in the same map.
2. Generated an R script that specifically calculates the length of the boundary between cell type 1 and 2 for one output file. The output of the script is simply one number: the value of boundary for that specific file/timepoint, called CellBoundary.

What I want to do now:
The R script only works for one single file. However, as I am simulating up to 100.000 MCS, I have as much as 1000 files. I would like to plot the output of the R script against time. So, I would want to generate some kind of code that could simply make R find these 1000 files, run them one after the other automatically and then store the output in a new csv file which would only have two columns: MCS and boundary length.

What I tried so far:
I am pretty new to all of this, so I am a bit stuck. However, I looked into bash scripting and standard input. 
So, would it be possible if I compress my 1000 files into one Zip-file and use this as a standard input for R, then generating the 1000 data values that I need so that I can simply plot this? 
By doing executing something like: "cat compressed_files | boundarycalculation.R"? I already tried this with some easier examples (with input file "a b c d" and an R-script saying "print lines") but then it says:
cat input | test.R
cat: input: No such file or directory
So, is this the right way of doing this after all, or should I look for something totally different?

Btw these are parts of my R script in case that might be of any use (where I thus would want the PIF file to be a different one each time I run the script):

```
# read file to a data frame
pixelDf <- read.delim("mcs_000000.pif", header = FALSE) 
# remove columns with only example values 
pixelDf <- pixelDf[, -(7:14)] 
# convert data frame to data table 
pixelDt <- data.table(pixelDf)
# set column names
setnames(pixelDt, c("cell_id", "cell_type", "x", "y"))

.....

# index horizEdgeDt with the key of vertEdgeDt (cell_id) to get both columns
# in one place, and add up the edges
cellDt <- horizEdgeDt[vertEdgeDt,.(cell_type,perimeter = numHorizEdges + numVertEdges)]

cellBoundary <- cellDt$boundary[cellDt$cell_type=="1"]
cellBoundary
```

And in the end I thus would want to generate a csv file with cellBoundary for each MCS. So I guess adding something like an append function to my R script would also be good. So if anyone would have any ideas on this that would help me further, I'd be very grateful! Thanks in advance.

**Update**

Okay, so, now I tried to do this in R only by adding:

```
fileNames <- Sys.glob("*.pif")

for (fileName in fileNames) {
```

before my script

and changing

```
# read file to a data frame
pixelDf <- read.delim("mcs_000000.pif", header = FALSE)
```

into

```
pixelDf <- read.delim("fileName", header = FALSE)
```

and adding

```
write.csv(outputTable, "Output.csv", append = TRUE, row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE) }
```

at the end of the script as to generate a new csv with each row based on the output from one file.
However, this gives the error:

```
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In write.csv(outputTable, "Output.csv", append = TRUE,  ... : 
attempt to set 'append' ignored
2: In write.csv(outputTable, "Output.csv", append = TRUE,  ... : 
attempt to set 'append' ignored
etc
```

Comment: `write.csv` has an `append` parameter.

Comment: As hrbrmstr suggests,  `?write.csv` would have saved you some time and trouble.

Comment: Thanks! I actually did incorporate that at first, so that it generated one output file for each input file. It was like this:
'write.csv(outputTable, row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE, file ="Output.csv")'

So now I tried that with the append function and added something like this at the end of my R script. 

'write.csv(outputTable, "Output.csv", append = TRUE, row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)" '

However, this gives the following errors: 

'In write.csv(outputTable, "Output.csv", append = TRUE,  ... :
  attempt to set 'append' ignored'.

Comment: you're probably getting the warning because the file doesn't exist, so nothing can be "appened" to it. However, after the first call (which results in a warning), the file should be created so you shouldn't have the second warning... (I didn't get through your script though so I might be missing something...)

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it now! The problem was not that the file was not there though, but rather that I could apparently not assign append to a write.csv function. So, I solved it with 
    write.table(cellPerimeter, file = "Output.csv", append = TRUE, col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)

and this actually exactly produced what I was looking for!

Comment: Makes sense, `help(write.csv)` actually says *"Attempts to change 'append', 'col.names', 'sep', 'dec' or 'qmethod' are ignored, with a warning."* (I never realized that, my first thought was the same as @hrbrmstr, et al.)